# How to use java.util.Date in Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis

I'm using Axis2 1.5.2 to pass Dates between client/server.  But when using java.util.Date Axis2 throws this error:

```
date string can not be less than 19 characters.
```

Anyone knows a workaround or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4370?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) in Axis2. My guess is that the expectation of `DateTime` is what is causing that error versus it is now `Date`. It appears that some have been able to switch to a `Calendar` type which cured their issue.

When inter-operating between a .NET client and an Axis2 WS, type differencing surfaced so we would opt for primitive types, in this instance we used a long to hold the milliseconds, then converted it to a .NET DateTime representation. You could always switch to using a long/milliseconds and bypass the type all together.

Comment: Hello sir, I am using EFS api and calling one function with begdate and enddate but I am getting same error "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Receiver] date string can not be less than 19 charactors" can you please go to this URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272341/getting-error-of-date-string-can-not-be-less-than-19-charactors-in-efs-api

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `Axis2` doesn't support `java.util.Date`.

I had the same issue, but I was able to overcome this problem by using `Calendar` class.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Axis2 1.5.2 and it does support java.util.Date.
Basically you need to know in which format you need to send Date ? either yy-MM-dd or yy/MM/DD HH:SS etc....?
Depending on the format, you should use `SimpleDateFormat` and parse your date.