# Getting Error of date string can not be less than 19 charactors in EFS API

Tags: php, api

Hello I am working on EFS API, I have one form, right now I am posting static data with **client ID**, **enddate** and **begdate**. I am calling **getchildTransaction** function.

But when I submit the form I am getting follwoing error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Receiver]
>   date string can not be less than 19 charactors in

How to pass date ? I am passing following parameter value :

```
$soapFunctionParameters = Array('username' => "************", 'password' => "*******",'clientID'=>$_POST['clientID'],'begDate' => "2017-08-18T13:20:47-07:00",'endDate' => "2017-09-18T13:20:47-07:00") ;
```

**What should be the date format begDate and  endDate why I am getting this error please suggest me.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FIrst check the date format accepted by the EFS API then pass the data.

Comment: I read the doc but date format is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown by the Soap PHP SOAP extension when it validates the request, not by the API you're calling.

Check that the parameters you're providing match the WSDL.

For DateTime types, an [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string is expected, make sure you're providing that. Note that PHP DateTime::ISO8601 is actually flawed, and you should use DateTime::ATOM.